# yanking by line number in vim

Tags: vim, yank

I have a file and I want to do the following.

```
- copy every n lines starting from m (m,m+n,m+2n, ...)
- copy line number 2, 5, 27, ... by specifying line numbers.
```

THanks

Answer (score 7):

To copy every N lines, you can use `:global` with an expression that selects the lines:

```
:let @a = ''
:g/^/if line('.') % 3 == 0 | yank A | endif
```

For explicit lines, I would sequentially call the `:yank` command:

```
2yank a | 5yank A | 27yank A
```

This uses yanking into the uppercase register to append to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But 1. where are n and m in your first code? 2. what's the difference between a and A in the second code?

Comment: I think n=3 in your example.

Comment: Yes, I chose n=3, and you can just add an offset: `(line('.') + 1) % 3`; experiment a bit, and you'll see.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the `:g` solution, Ingo posted, you can also use an `:s` command.

First you need to prepare the pattern. For example to explicitly match every third line,
you can use the pattern `\%3l\|\%6l\|\%9l`, etc.

So first let's save the generated pattern inside a variable (to simplify it a bit, we only consider the first 100 lines):

```
:let lines=range(3,100,3)
```

This creates a list of all line numbers, starting from 3 and incrementing by 3, Note, if you need some special line numbers, that don't follow any arithemtic rule, simply define the list as this:

```
:let lines=[2,5,26,57,99]
```

Then we need to generate a pattern out of it, which we can use inside an `:s` command:

```
:call map(lines, '''\%''.v:val.''l''')
```

This translates the line numbers into a pattern of the form `\%`*number*`l`. So we have a pattern matching each desired line, but first we need to initalize a resulting list variable:

```
:let result = []
```

We can now feed this to the `:s` command:

```
:exe ":%s/". join(lines, '.*\|'). '/\=add(result, submatch(0))/n'
```

All matching lines are now contained in the list `result` and can e.g. be copied to the clipboard by using:

```
:let @+=join(result, "\n")
```

or you can paste it into a scratch buffer:

```
:new +exe\ append(0,result)
```

(Note, that the space between exe and the append call needs to be escaped).

Please also note, that this solution requires at least [Vim Patch 7.3.627](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_dev/Rbx48dxW8Fs/R14P09nNB8UJ)

Depending on the situation I would either use this method or the one pointed out by Ingo.